# Why does locally changing a deep copy of a Vuex store object result in that change being applied to the Vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuex, lodash

In my code below I first try to make a copy of some data from the Vuex store in order to change one small thing before sending it to the backend without changing the data in the store itself. I use Lodash cloneDeep() to make a deep copy and store it in a local variable. I would assume that any change I make to this local variable wont affect the data in the store. But it turns out there is still a reference from this local variable to the state in the store even though I made a deep copy.

```
let localCopy = _.cloneDeep(store.getters["course/course"]);
localCopy.image.file = null;
```

I tried many different ways to make this copy but they all keep the reference to the state in the store intact. I'm looking for a way to make this copy and change it however I like without also changing the the store state.

My store looks like this

```
export default {
namespaced: true,
state: {
    course: {
        id: null,
        name: "naamloos",
        description: "...",
        image: null,
        information_slides: [],
        question_slides: [],
    }
},
mutations: {
    loadCourse(state, value) {
        state.course = value;
    },

    unloadCourse(state) {
        state.course = {
            id: null,
            name: "",
            description: "",
            image: {
                file: null,
                path: null,
            },
            information_slides: [],
            question_slides: [],
        }
    },

    updateIds(state, value) {
        state.course = value;
    },

    updateImage(state, value) {
        state.course.image = value;
    },

    addQuestionSlide(state, value){
        state.course.question_slides.push(value);
    },

    deleteQuestionSlide(state, index){
        let indexInQuestionSlidesArray = state.course.question_slides.findIndex(item => {return item.index === index});
        state.course.question_slides.splice(indexInQuestionSlidesArray, 1);
        this.dispatch('course/resetIndexes', state);
    },

    addInformationSlide(state, value){
        state.course.information_slides.push(value);
    },

    deleteInformationSlide(state, index){
        let indexInInformationSlidesArray = state.course.information_slides.findIndex(item => {return item.index === index});
        state.course.information_slides.splice(indexInInformationSlidesArray, 1);
        this.dispatch('course/resetIndexes', state);

    },

},
actions: {
    resetIndexes(_state, state) {
        let merged = Object.values([...state.course.information_slides, ...state.course.question_slides].reduce((r, o) => (r[o.index] = o, r), {}));
        for(let i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
            merged[i].index = i;
        }
    }
},
getters: {
    course (state) {
        return state.course;
    },

    id (state) {
        return state.course.id;
    },

    name (state) {
        return state.course.name;
    },

    description (state) {
        return state.course.description;
    },

    informationSlides (state) {
        return state.course.information_slides;
    },

    questionSlides (state) {
        return state.course.question_slides;
    },

    selectedSlide: (state) => (index) => {
        let allSlides = [...state.course.information_slides, ...state.course.question_slides];
        let selectedSlide = allSlides.filter(slide => {
            return slide.index === index;
        })
        return selectedSlide[0];
    },

    image (state) {
        return state.course.image;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
let localCopy = _.cloneDeep({ ...store.getters["course/course"] });
localCopy.image.file = null;
```

Comment: I tried it but it made no difference

Comment: Can you share un example of your store?